# Is there any order requirement for binding multi_passthrough_initiator_sockets?

Tags: systemc

I have a SystemC hierarchy top->middle->leaf and trying to bind a `multi_passthrough_initiator_socket` in *leaf* to a socket of the same type in its parent module *middle*. The socket in *middle* then binds to a target socket in *top*.

The bindings are done in `middle::before_end_of_elaboration()`:

```
leaf->i_socket.bind(i_socket)
```

and `top::before_end_of_elaboration()`:

```
middle->i_socket.bind(t_socket)
```

This creates an exception when the code in *middle* is executed - I noticed that the code in *top* is called before (it seems that before_end_of_elaboration() is not called depth-first).

The workaround is to do the bindings in *middle* already in its constructor, which suggests that there is some kind of ordering requirement. Does anybody know about this / can suggest a clean solution?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to post this to Accellera support forums. http://forums.accellera.org/forum/14-systemc-tlm-transaction-level-modeling/

This is either an implementation bug, or undocumented limitation of TLM library.

I've experimented with this case myself, and here is what I've found:

- There is no ordering requirements
- But you are not allowed to use before_end_of_elaboration() for tlm socket binding

Here is my test example:

```
struct test : sc_module {
    tlm_utils::multi_passthrough_initiator_socket<test> leaf{"leaf"};
    tlm_utils::multi_passthrough_initiator_socket<test> middle{"middle"};
    tlm_utils::simple_target_socket<test>  target{"target"};
    test(sc_module_name);
protected:
    void before_end_of_elaboration();
};
```

Option 1 - Works

```
test::test(sc_module_name)
{
    leaf.bind(target);
    middle.bind(leaf);
}

void test::before_end_of_elaboration() {}
```

Option 2 - Works

```
test::test(sc_module_name)
{
    middle.bind(leaf);
    leaf.bind(target);
}

void test::before_end_of_elaboration() {}
```

Option 3 - Fails with Error: (E126) sc_export instance already bound

```
test::test(sc_module_name)
{}

void test::before_end_of_elaboration() {
    middle.bind(leaf);
    leaf.bind(target);
}
```

Now the reason for this behavior is that TLM library uses `before_end_of_elaboration` callbacks to implement support of hierarchical bindings (check source code of `multi_passthrough_initiator_socket` yourself). So user code should complete all socket bindings before this. And since there is no callbacks before `before_end_of_elaboration`, you can only bind TLM sockets inside constructors.

Please note that this is not the case for signal ports, which you can bind using `before_end_of_elaboration`, in any order :

```
struct test : sc_module {
    sc_in<int> leaf0{"leaf0"};
    sc_in<int> leaf1{"leaf1"};
    sc_in<int> middle0{"middle0"};
    sc_in<int> middle1{"middle1"};
    sc_signal<int> sig{"sig"};

    test(sc_module_name);
protected:
    void before_end_of_elaboration();
};


test::test(sc_module_name)
{
}

void test::before_end_of_elaboration()
{
    leaf0(middle0); // OK
    middle0(sig);   // OK
    middle1(sig);   // OK
    leaf1(middle1); // OK
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your investigation. Interesting, we have also seen the problem with "already bound" when using before_end_of_elaboration(), but suspected it is a bug in the implementation that only occurs if there is more than one SystemC top-level module.

Comment: I will try to get confirmation that before_end_of_elaboration() should not be used for TLM2 socket binding - in that case I will refactor which solves the problem.